# Obtain the value variable

Tags: javascript, html

how can I get this value variable with javascript?

```
<div class="sample-row-xxxxxx">
<div class="co-1 xxxxxxx">value</div>
</div>
```

There is also an HTML code on a page that if you notice the code in the code is x which is not constant in the original text of these x and I do not know how to get the value from them.
How can I get value variable now? please guide me

Comment: hmm, how about.
document.getElementByClassName("col-1")[0].innerText ?

Comment: Can you explain more about what exactly you want to do and what did you try so far with the sample.

Comment: please make the question clear.

Comment: At what point you are trying to get the `value`? Any event? Also, are there more elements with same structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelector` to get elements on the page, with attribute selector. `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` accepts CSS selectors like jQuery.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('[class*="sample-row"] .co-1').innerText)
console.log(document.querySelector('[class*="sample-row"]').className.replace(/sample-row-/, ''))
```

```html
<div class="sample-row-xxxxxx">
<div class="co-1 xxxxxxx">value</div>
</div>
```

the selector will find any element that have `sample-row` somewhere inside class attribute that have `.col-1` element inside.

If you're know for sure that is at the beginning of the class you can use `[class^="sample-row"]` selector instead but you can have other classes before sample-row.